# R output to html file

Tags: r

Having inherited some R Script, I need to execute the script on a schedule and push the results into a html file.

In essence, automating clicking Knit > Knit to HTML.

I'd like to keep options open and as such, would like to know if

a) Can you do this in the R script itself and if so, how?

b) Can you do this via command line with an argument?

thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run knitr from the command line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943695/what-is-the-knitr-equivalent-of-r-cmd-sweave-myfile-rnw