# How to open a local html file from R in an operating system independent way?

Tags: r

How to open a local html file from R in an operating system independent way?

For demonstration purposes, assume that the file is called `test.html` and is in the working directory.

#### initial thoughts

- `system('gnome-open test.html')`

  - This works on Ubuntu
- `browseURL(paste('file://', getwd(),'test.html', sep='/'))`

  - This works on Ubuntu, but it feels like a bit of a hack and I'm not certain whether it would work on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

You might find my `open.file.in.OS` function useful, sources can be found [here](https://github.com/rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/convert.R).

A short summary about what this function does:

1. Check platform
2. Based on platform, call:

   - `shell.exec` on Windows
   - `open` with `system` on Mac
   - and `xdg-open` with `system` on other Unix-like operating system
3. Uses `shQuote` on the privided file

---

**Update**: See now the `openFileInOS` in the `pander` package.

```
library(pander)
openFileInOS("d:/del/dt/a.html")
```

*References*: this function is a forked version of David Hajage's `convert` function can be found [here](https://github.com/eusebe/ascii/blob/master/R/export.r).

Comment: +1 That looks really cool. For my particular application, I'd like to minimise dependencies. Thus, I'd still prefer a built in function.

Comment: Well, you can just copy that function to your `.Rprofile` in your home dir without any additional dependencies - and have an OS independent function that can open up any file format in your OS. **Otherwise** just use something like `openHTML <- function(x) browseURL(paste0('file://', file.path(getwd(), x)))`

Comment: Thanks, that's it. The combination of file.path with browseURL is probably what would meet my current needs most.

Comment: Hi @JeromyAnglim you can use the `openFileInOS` function of daroczig's `pander` package.

Comment: With pander package you can do like this: `library(htmlwidgets)
openFileInOS("d:/del/dt/a.html")`

Answer (score 8):

*I just wanted to pull the **answer** given by @daroczig out of the comments and into an answer. If @darcozig wants to post this as a separate answer, I'll delete this copy.*

```
openHTML <- function(x) browseURL(paste0('file://', file.path(getwd(), x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `file.path` function to construct the file path.

```
 file.path(..., fsep = .Platform$file.sep)


 ...: character vectors.

fsep: the path separator to use.
```

By default it will use the current os path separator.

For example

```
> file.path ("", "home", "phoxis", "paragraph")
[1] "/home/phoxis/paragraph"
```

This generates my file "/home/phoxis/paragraph"

Note the blank string "" at the beginning. This forces to ad an extra "/" in my case to generate the absolute path. Adjust to generate absolute or relative path as per your need and have a look at `?file.path`

I think this will fulfil your needs

Comment: OP wants to run the appropriate application to launch the file, not just construct an OS-agnostic path to it.