# Knit2html not replicating functionality of Knit HTML button in R Studio

Tags: r, ubuntu, knitr, rstudio

I'm trying to write a Bash script in Ubuntu 10.04 that opens a Python file which exports a CSV, and then runs the following Rscript with the goal of exporting a HTML with plots from Dashboard.Rmd:

```
require(knitr)
setwd('/home/sensors/Desktop/')
knit2html('Dashboard.Rmd')
browseURL('Dashboard.html')
```

Dashboard.Rmd is an R markdown that calls read.csv on the csv from the first step, makes a data frame and creates plots, but that part's working fine. According to [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646665/how-to-convert-r-markdown-to-html-i-e-what-does-knit-html-do-in-rstudio-0-9) I figure that Rscript should replicate the action of pressing "Knit HTML" in R Studio. However, the html it creates is identical to the last time Knit HTML was pressed; i.e. even if the CSV is different, the html doesn't reflect the change.

I also tried using a separate line for knit and markdownToHTML with the same effect. It seems like it doesn't source the code from the Rmd when performing knit. It *does* update the html properly when I enter the commands from that Rscript into the console of R Studio with Dashboard.Rmd open. However I'm not sure how to translate that into a Bash script. I also tried knit2html with envir=new.env(), envir=R_GlobalEnv, and envir=parent.frame() with no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you turn on cache? (`cache=TRUE`) You'd better let us know what is inside `Dashboard.Rmd`, or give a minimal reproducible example. BTW, I recommend you to `setwd('/home/sensors/Desktop/')` before `knit2html('Dashboard.Rmd')` (you do not need to specify the `output` argument). Absolute paths are bad in general.

Comment: It actually worked when I set cache=FALSE in the code chunk. I'm relatively new to programming so I didn't know not to use absolute paths, but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks so much!

Comment: That is fine. I edited your code to make it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that this was an artifact of `cache=TRUE` -- the HTML file was not changed because everything was cached.