# How can I remove the prefix (index indicator) [1] in knitr output?

Tags: r, knitr

Standard R output looks like this

```
> 3
[1] 3
```

To remove the prefix [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znoet.png) you can use

```
> cat(3)
3
```

Is there a way to remove this globally? Or do you have to wrap `cat()` around everything?

**Further to that, I'm using this within knitr, so if there isn't an R global setting, there may be a knitr wide setting, I did look, but couldn't see one.**

Edit: It was asked why one would want this, something like if you wanted to structure a report like the below. The `[1]` is just not needed and means nothing to none R users (aka, the audience).

[image]

Additional Info: In knitr you can use \Sexpr{} or `r ...` to evaluate something in line, and in that scenario it doesn't print the `[1]`. For example if you had:

```
There are `r sum(mtcars$cyl==6)` cars with 6 cylinders.
```

You would get:

*There are 7 cars with 6 cylinders.*

As your output, not:

*There are `[1]` 7 cars with 6 cylinders.*

Comment: What platform are you on?  R, RStudio? Version? Are you in Linux or Windows, Mac?

Comment: I'm using R(3.0.2) in RStudio (0.98.501) on a Mac (10.9.1). I know on a Mac you get the [1] whether you're using RStudio, R (in R) or R (in terminal). Looks to be the same in Linux terminal too.

Comment: Kintr has [hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks). Instead using `cat`, I would suggest giving a try to the `pander` method in my `pander` package, that returns the markdown representation of the R objects. See more details e.g. at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599948/replacing-the-print-function-in-knitr-chunk-evaluation/15600673#15600673

Comment: Thanks @Thell, not a duplicate though, as there is no solution in there to globally remove the [1] from output, only via a wrapper function, and that was focused on copying the output, this is for use within reproducible research etc. Feel free to remove your comment.

Comment: @daroczig, thanks. See my (new) additional info in the question. I'm guessing that is the result of hook settings, so I'll have a look down that path.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nothing is impossible. Take a look at what can be done with [knitr hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks).
Have fun!
[<sub><sup>Rmarkdown script gist</sup></sub>](https://gist.github.com/Thell/9689152)

```
# A Prefix nulling hook.

# Make sure to keep the default for normal processing.
default_output_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("output")

# Output hooks handle normal R console output.
knitr::knit_hooks$set( output = function(x, options) {

  comment <- knitr::opts_current$get("comment")
  if( is.na(comment) ) comment <- ""
  can_null <- grepl( paste0( comment, "\\s*\\[\\d?\\]" ),
                     x, perl = TRUE)
  do_null <- isTRUE( knitr::opts_current$get("null_prefix") )
  if( can_null && do_null ) {
    # By default R print output aligns at the right brace.
    align_index <- regexpr( "\\]", x )[1] - 1
    # Two cases: start or newline
    re <- paste0( "^.{", align_index, "}\\]")
    rep <- comment
    x <- gsub( re, rep,  x )
    re <- paste0( "\\\n.{", align_index, "}\\]")
    rep <- paste0( "\n", comment )
    x <- gsub( re, rep,  x )
  }

  default_output_hook( x, options )

})

knitr::opts_template$set("kill_prefix"=list(comment=NA, null_prefix=TRUE))
```

Normal:

````
```{r}
print( 1:50 )
```
````

```
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
## [24] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
## [47] 47 48 49 50
```

Null prefix

````
```{r, null_prefix=TRUE}
print( 1:50 )
```
````

```
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
## 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
## 47 48 49 50
```

Set as default (and remove comment string):

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(opts.label="kill_prefix")
```

```{r}
print( 1:50 )
```
````

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 47 48 49 50
```

Ensure we aren't killing strings with [:digit:] patterns.

````
```{r}
print( paste0( paste0("[", 1:50), "]" ),quote = FALSE)
```
````

```
 [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]  [5]  [6]  [7]  [8]  [9]  [10] [11] [12] [13] [14]
 [15] [16] [17] [18] [19] [20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [27] [28]
 [29] [30] [31] [32] [33] [34] [35] [36] [37] [38] [39] [40] [41] [42]
 [43] [44] [45] [46] [47] [48] [49] [50]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Thell. Clearly not a trivial solution, but great that you wrote something that can literally be dropped in.

Comment: Great solution! Any tips on what can also be done to remove the quotation marks around outputted strings (e.g., "my string")? Looking to implement a `quote=NA` option.

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head yet I am confident it can be done.

Answer (score -2):

Can't be done. But I would hesitate to either do it, or just wrap everything in a `cat`. Why?

Firstly, R users expect to see the `[1]` label, and its helpful when the vector is longer than one line, or if its a matrix with rows and column labels. Why do you want to do this?

Secondly, now you know **why** you want to do this, write a function named after the reason you want to do this, that does this, and wrap your outputs in that function. Because I reckon if you want fine control over the output you are pretty soon going to go "Hmmm `cat` isn't quite cutting it for me, I want to change this and that and this and that" and that's easier if you have wrapped your output in a function you can change. At first it might just be `cleanprint=function(...){cat(...)}` but then its easier to move on from there by redefining `cleanprint` than tweaking `cat`. You might want to use `sprintf`, or set the number of decimal digits or something.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Spacedman! I've edited the question to add a why. But from your first sentence I'm guessing if it can't be done, the why becomes a bit irrelevant :)

Comment: We don't always write for R users.