# Output html from function during knitr output

Tags: html, r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

This is a small sample of many separate analyses I want to run together, flagging each analysis with a heading generated in the function.  The first heading outputs as expected, but the headings generated by the function do not. How can I get the headings generated by the function to format as html?

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

RStudio 1.0.136

knitr 1.15.1
```

````
```{r initialize, echo=F, comment=NA}

htmPrint = function(htm) {
    structure(htm, class='knit_asis')
    }

doAnalysis = function(dat, depVar, indVar) {

    print(htmPrint(paste0('<h3>AusMCP1 on ', indVar, '</h3>')))
    eval(parse(text=paste0('print(summary(lm(', depVar, '~', indVar, ', data=dat)))')))
    print(htmPrint('<hr>'))
    }

demoData = data.frame(dep1=rnorm(100), dep2=rnorm(100), ind1=runif(100), ind2=runif(100), ind3=runif(100))

varDep = names(demoData)[1:2]
varInd = names(demoData)[3:5]
```

This is a small sample of many separate analyses I want to run together, flagging each analysis with a heading generated in the function.

I could use *results=asis* in the chunk command, but it produces
unwanted formatting and extraneous output in the analysis output.

```{r doAnalyses}
htmPrint('<h2>Begin analyses</h2>')

for (k in 1:length(varDep)) for (i in 1:length(varInd)) doAnalysis(demoData, varDep[k], varInd[i])
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use `results = 'asis'` and just alter you function to get the output that you want.  I'm going to use some methods referenced in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599948/replacing-the-print-function-in-knitr-chunk-evaluation) that make use of the package `pander`.

You don't have to use your htmPrint function as you can get the same functionality with `cat` and html tags. Then you'd just use `print_lm` instead of `print` and remove the summary, since you're getting nice tabular output.

````
```{r initialize, echo=F, comment=NA}

library(pander)

#Use the pander print method to print the model tables.  
#You could use other package print methods as well.

print_lm <- function (x, ...) UseMethod("pander")

doAnalysis = function(dat, depVar, indVar) {

    cat('<h3>AusMCP1 on ', indVar, '</h3>')
    eval(parse(text=paste0('print_lm(summary(lm(', depVar, '~', indVar, ', data=dat)))')))
    cat('<hr>')
    }

demoData = data.frame(dep1=rnorm(100), dep2=rnorm(100), ind1=runif(100), ind2=runif(100), ind3=runif(100))

varDep = names(demoData)[1:2]
varInd = names(demoData)[3:5]
```

I  use *results=asis* and changed the output of your doAnalysis function to create formatted output.

```{r doAnalyses, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
cat('<h2>Begin analyses</h2>')

for (k in 1:length(varDep)) for (i in 1:length(varInd)) doAnalysis(demoData, varDep[k], varInd[i])
```
````

[image]

You could also do all of the modelling beforehand, and use the `broom` package to tidy all of your model summaries to your liking, then print them out using `kable()` or tabular print method of your choice.

Comment: Doesn't quite do what I need.  I'd like to display the summary info. Using pander appears to generate a single line for the intercept in big bold letters, a line of headings with a nonbreakable space character, and the regression coefficient that doesn't line up with the headings.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean about the formatting and alignment in `pander`, seeing as the above screenshot is the code output using `pander`.   If you want to have the full text version of the summary, you may have to define your own print method to do so in the appropriate format.

Comment: My css is generating output that looks different from the output you displayed.  I was hoping for a simpler way to do this without redefining my css and using pander.  Isn't there some way to format html in the output when it's generated inside a function?

Comment: You'd have to go deep under the hood with `summary` for that.  What you could do is right a function using `coefs()` or `broom` functions to get the variables then output an html table in the format you desire.