# What does “Knit HTML” do in Rstudio 0.98?

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to figure out what command and default options RStudio uses when pressing the "knit HTML" button in RStudio version 0.98.1091 because I get a slightly different intermediate markdown file when I run the `knit()` function from the console.

Specifically, when I use the following header for the R markdown file:

```
---
title: "Report Title"
author: Daddy the Runner
date:  "`r format(Sys.time(), '%A, %B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

I get the following markdown file when pressing the "Knit HTML" button:

```
# Report Title
Daddy the Runner  
`r format(Sys.time(), '%A, %B %d, %Y')`
```

When I execute the following command: `knit("myReport.Rmd")`, I get the following markdown file:

```
---
title: "Report Title"
author: Daddy the Runner
date:  "Saturday, January 10, 2015"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

Clearly the RStudio button is generating the intermediate markdown file using some other options but I can't find any information about it in the RStudio docs.

The key issue is the date line.  For some reason, RStudio doesn't execute the inline r chunk in the header when making the markdown file.  (However, it does get executed before generating the final HTML.)  Whereas, the `knit()` function call does execute the inline chunk while generating the markdown file.

The only other difference I noticed in the two markdown files is related to the generation of plots.  The two methods generate different sized graphics (command line: 504 x 504) versus (button: 672 x 480) and place them in different directories.

I tried the recommendation in this [What commands are run when pressing "Knit HTML" on an R Markdown file in Rstudio 0.96?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646665/how-to-convert-r-markdown-to-html-i-e-what-does-knit-html-do-in-rstudio-0-9) question to insert a `Sys.sleep(30)` call but that did not provide any information about what call RStudio used to knit the document.  It did pause the output in the R Markdown console window which was unnecessary because RStudio keeps all of the output anyway.  What I didn't see in the output was the command RStudio issued.

Any insight to the nature of these differences would be greatly appreciated.  While I like using IDE environments and the conveniences they provide, I really like to understand what it is they are doing so I can better anticipate their behavior.

Comment: iirc, `knitr::knit` if knitting is required then `rmarkdown::render` which calls pandoc with options

Comment: @rawr you remembered correctly.  I was able to reproduce the RStudio results using rmarkdown::render and there was an extensive list of pandoc options shown in the console output.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Either of you can copy and paste the comment as the answer below, and the OP can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

As @rawr pointed out in the comments:

```
rmarkdown::render('your_document.Rmd', 'html_document', 'new_titel.html')
```

works and creates the same document as the `Knit HTML` button.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the RMarkdown tab (right of Console tab) it looks like they run `knitr::knit` and then a fairly involved `pandoc` shell line

`/usr/local/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc filename.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output filename.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --template /home/me/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --variable 'theme:flatly' --include-in-header /tmp/user/1001/RtmpKz5GnI/rmarkdown-str3bba3848bd7b.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=/home/cd/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlight`

From the very first `/usr/local/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc` I infer that they bring their own `pandoc`, probably figuring duplication is better than debugging to play nice with everyone's idiosyncratic `pandoc` versions.

---

So to me it looks like RStudio is doing the following:

1. knit
2. pandoc with their special pandoc version and a lot of flags

and step #2 is where the interpretation of your header

```
---
title: "Report Title"
author: Daddy the Runner
date:  "`r format(Sys.time(), '%A, %B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
```

happens.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it currently uses the `html_document` function in the RMarkdown package