# Why does the Knit drop-down in RStudio disappear?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Q: Why does the Knit drop-down in RStudio disappear when I add a knit option to the YAML header of my R Markdown file?

Normally I see the Knit button with drop-down option (like this [image: knit01]) when viewing a .Rmd in RStudio, . But the drop-down option disappears (so I only see [image]) after I add the following code to the YAML header in my .Rmd:

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_dir = "../output") })
```

I add that code because I want my output to go to a different directory than my source .Rmd.

I can change the ordering of my `output` fields (e.g., `pdf_document`, `word_document`) to Knit (without drop-down) to get a .pdf or .docx as I need. But go back and forth between the two often. So this work-around becomes very tedious.

This question appears to relate to [What does “Knit HTML” do in Rstudio 0.98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881289/what-does-knit-html-do-in-rstudio-0-98) and [Knit Directory drop down menu](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000814347-Knit-Directory-drop-down-menu).

Comment: I don't currently have an answer, but it looks like this thread (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/913) may be related to your issue.