# R Bookdown _bookdown.yml

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Bookdown has many configuration options and I am finding it hard to understand how to know whether an option exists, and the logic behind where these options are stated.

Specifically I am finding it hard to describe what *kind* of options go in `_bookdown.yml` given that there are at least two other places for stating options:

- In `_output.yml`,
- Arguments to function calls such as `bookdown::render_book`.

It doesn't appear to me that there's any sort of 1 to 1 mapping between `_bookdown.yml` and arguments to functions like `bookdown::render_book`, so `_bookdown.yml`doesn't seem to be just a different way of recording options to function calls.

We can see in the source code that `_bookdown.yml' is controlling some of the [config options](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/7c09c9b22605686291e583ccad671ff7d84a1b35/R/html.R#L539) but not all of them.

So - to rephrase the question - why is `_bookdown.yml` a separate config file and where/what is the definition of what it should contain?

To take a representative example, there is a `chapter_name` option that can be used in `_bookdown.yml`.  I have the following questions:

1. How are we supposed to know that this is an option, given that it is not referenced in the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bookdown/bookdown.pdf) or even in the example [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html).
2. Once we know it exists, how do I found out what effect it has?  Do all of these options get passed to other packages (e.g. pandoc, rmarkdown)?  The only place I can find reference to `chapter_name` is in the CRAN source code for [bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/7c09c9b22605686291e583ccad671ff7d84a1b35/R/html.R#L539), and even there I can't really figure out how it's being used.

Note, the discussion of `_bookdown.yml` by the author is [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html), but I still don't fully understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some results of investigations into the codebase:

We can see that the 'config' variable in `bookdown::render_book` is populated from `_bookdown.yml` [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/1254a81864c7d0e1d165eda58d9fb08fe3a9bc71/R/render.R#L63), via a function called `load_config` which can be found in [`utils.R`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/R/utils.R#L79).

`load_config` seems to do two things - it stores the contents of `config` within a master options list called `opts`, of which `config` is just one element, and then returns that `config` element.

Note that `opts` is initially defined [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/R/utils.R#L247). It is created from a `knitr:::new_defaults` which can be found [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/f02600d24a9628c8a376df41078756dc9e63bfc2/R/defaults.R#L3).

The `config` variable then appears in multiple parts of the codebase.

The [following code](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/1254a81864c7d0e1d165eda58d9fb08fe3a9bc71/R/render.R#L88) is representative:

```
  if (is.na(new_session)) {
    new_session = FALSE
    if (is.logical(config[['new_session']])) new_session = config[['new_session']]
  }
```

So we can see that if `new_session` is passed directly to `bookdown::render_book` as a function argument, it is used.  Otherwise an attempt is made to load it from the `_bookdown.yml` file.

The `config` is passed around a lot as an argument within `bookdown::render_book`.  So for instance, we can see it being used in the [`source_files`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/R/utils.R#L93) function in `utils.R`.

What do we conclude?  `_bookdown.yml` allows you to populate a list of global options of the `bookdown` package.  Whenever you see `config` (which is a list) being using the the codebase, you can set elements of this list by populating `_bookdown.yml`

I have not managed to find a comprehensive list of the options that can be specified in `_bookdown.yml` but one way of easily finding out what is possible is to [search for examples on Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filename%3A_bookdown.yml).

Comment: The last link does not work. It says "We could not perform this search
Must include at least one user, organization, or repository"

Comment: This question was asked and answered a long time ago, possibly before the bookdown book was written? Is there better documentation now that should be pointed out?