# Convert **RPubs** `html` file back to `Rmd`

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a straightforward way for getting the **RPubs** back to `Rmd` file for easier R workflow? There is great explanation for `knitr` `knit2html` [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646665/how-to-convert-r-markdown-to-html-i-e-what-does-knit-html-do-in-rstudio-0-9)

Comment: You could, using Pandoc, convert HTML back to markdown and get an `.md` file. But you can't tell what R code was to get a certain result, so you can't go from `.md` back to `.Rmd`.

Comment: HTML files often have just results from evaluating code, not the code itself. You can't tell what R code I just ran to get the result `6`. Maybe it was `mean(c(5, 7))`. Maybe `mean(c(4, 6, 8))`. Maybe it was `sample(1:10, size = 1)`...

Comment: Now, if you know all the code chunks had `echo = TRUE`, you could do pretty good. You won't necessarily know any options specified in the YAML. And you will still be out of luck for any in-line code expressions - you won't even be able to identify those. But I doubt anyone has written a tool for that.